# Allocating Sufficient Memory for a Known Number of Structs

Tags: c++, memory, graph, memory-management, constructor

First time implementing a graph where the total number of nodes is known when the constructor is called and performance is the highest priority.

Never allocated memory before, so the process is a little hazy.

The number of nodes required is (n*(n+1))/2 where n is the length of the string passed to the constructor.

```
#include <string>
struct ColorNode {
    ColorNode* lParent;
    ColorNode* rParent;
    char color;
};

class ParentGraph {
    std::string base;
    int len, nodes;

    ParentGraph(std::string b): base(b) {
        len = base.length();
        nodes = (len * (len + 1)) / 2;

        // how to allocate enough memory for number of copies of "ColorNode" equal to "nodes"?
    }
};
```

What is the best practice for allocating memory in this instance?

Will allocating the memory beforehand make a significant difference in performance?

It may turn out that an array or vector is a better choice, but really need the practice in both data structures and memory allocation.

Thanks for the consideration.

Comment: If you've never done anything with memory management, then "performance" is _not_ your priority.  You need to focus on safe, valid code.  Then worry about performance if it's ever a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
std::vector<ColorNode> nodes;
```

life will be very simple after that.

You can be helpful to std::vector if you know the size you want

```
auto nodes = std::vector<ColorNode>(size);
```

This will allocate a contiguous array on the heap for you, manage its growth, allocation, deallocation etc.

You will basically get the same in memory structure if you do `new ColorNode[size]` (or even `malloc(....)` if some evil person tried to persuade you that raw malloc will be faster). But you have to do all the nasty management yourself.

You only need to diverge from this advice if you have too many objects to fit into one contiguous memory block. If thats the case say so